# JS: Как правильно отправить сообщение в ВК?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api, request

Привет!

Мне нужно отправить пользователю ВК сообщение от имени сообщества. Нашел разные реализации, но выдает ошибку:

> Failed to load https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'XXXX.ru' is therefore not allowed access. If an
>   opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'
>   to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
    let token = 'XXXX';
    let user_id = 99999;
    let message = 'msg';
    let apiMsg = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send';

    let header = new Headers({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    })

    let data = {
        'user_id': user_id,
        'message': message,
        'access_token': token
    };

    let options = {
        mode: 'cors',
        header: header,
        'method': 'post',
        'payload': data
    };

    fetch(apiMsg, options)
        .then((data) => {
            return data.text()
        })
        .then((text) => {
            console.log(text)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message)
        })
```

Почему возникает ошибка, я же добил Access-Control-Allow-Origin? Как правильно?

Comment: Добавить его должен сервер. А он этого делать не будет, потому что, как я понимаю, Standalone API не предназначен для использования в браузере

Comment: Хотя стоит попробовать прописать no-cors, как советует текст ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Получилось только через PHP, Standalone API не предназначен для использования в браузере – andreymal

Comment: обясните по подребнее решение данной задачи